# Can't assign value to a struct field

Tags: c

Why does the following code:

```
struct number {
    int num1;
    int num2;
} arr[5];

arr[0].num1 = 1;

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

produces:

**main.c:8:8: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘**attribute**’ before ‘.’ token   arr[0].num1 = 1;**

but if I move line `arr[0].num1 = 1;` inside the `main` function, it works without producing the error?

Comment: you have to put the assignment statement in main()

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about elementary material that should be learned by reading a C primer or textbook and working on course assignments rather than by asking on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2):

The line

```
arr[0].num1 = 1;
```

is a [statement](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/statements), not a [declaration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/declarations).

All statements must be inside a function. It does not make sense to put statements outside a function, because in that case, it is unclear when these statements are supposed to be executed.

If you want to initialize `arr[0].num1` outside the function `main`, then you will have to initialize it as part of the declaration of `arr`, for example like this:

```
struct number {
    int num1;
    int num2;
} arr[5] = { {1,0},{0,0},{0,0},{0,0},{0,0} };
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd either have to create a function to store the statement or run it in the main() clause